# I’d like to mathematically solve this calculator game

Tags: recreational-mathematics, puzzle

The app [Calculator: The Game](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&hl=en-us&q=calculator%20the%20game&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJ39-ngv_VAhWFNSYKHQWNBFgQvwUIISgA&biw=375&bih=559) is a puzzle game in which players try to transform a given number into a goal number by using a finite number of operations. Some of these can be very tricky with a trial-and-error method, so I would like to learn how to solve an algorithm of sorts to help.

Here’s an example problem:

> Transform $111$ into $126$ in exactly $6$ moves using the following operations:
>
> - $x\operatorname{A}=x\times3$
> - $x\operatorname{B}=x-9$
> - $x\operatorname{C}=-x$
> - $x\operatorname{D}=\lfloor x/10\rfloor$
>
> where $x$ is the number on the display when the button is pressed)

So, for example, $111\operatorname{A}\operatorname{B}\operatorname{C}\operatorname{D}=-32$.

How could I conceive an **equality** with iterations of these operations **and solve it**?

Comment: Two helpful observations: $A$ always produces a multiple of $3$, $B$ leaves the remainder upon division by $3$, and $C$ "flips" the remainder upon division by $3$.  $111$ and $126$ are both multiples of $3$.

Comment: Almost a solution: $111 \ C\ D\ A\ A\ B\ B\ C = 126$

Comment: 111 D A C B C A = 126 seems to work

Comment: @GTonyJacobs  Nice. Also, the first two steps commute, and so do the last two steps, which gives three more related solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is an easy algorithm, which is what makes it a good puzzle.  Some things I would notice to cut down the search space, written as a stream of consciousness:
Thinking about rough magnitude, we are starting out about right.  Two $A$s and one $D$ leave us about where we started, so we need twice as many $A$s as $D$s.  In fact, two $A$s and a $D$ decrease the value, so we can't have four $A$s and two $D$s.  They probably created the puzzle to need all the operations, so I would bet on two $A$s and one $D$, but not be shocked if there are none of either.  Since we start positive and end positive we need an even number of $C$s.  If we don't have any $A$s or $D$s we can only subtract (or add if between $C$s) $9$ and that doesn't get us there, so two $A$s and one $D$ are confirmed.  Those will decrease the value, so we need the $+9$ that comes from sandwiching a $B$ between two $C$s.  The set of operations is then $AABCCD$ with the $B$ between the $C$s.  That doesn't leave much to try.